# #( in shell case statement

Tags: bash, configure, autotools, automake

I am trying to learn how a configure script in the gimp source code works by reading and trying to understand what each statement does.  I am at the beginning of the file and came across a case statement to that sets posix to on.  I cant undstand what the "#(" means.  Is it a comment or something else?

```
case `(set -o) 2>/dev/null` in #( 
       *posix*) : 
              set -o posix ;; #( 
       *) : 
           ;; 
esac
```

Comment: It is a comment.  It is often useful to have balanced parentheses in the file (for editors which jump to matching brace), and the purpose of the comment is to match the `)` at the end of the next case.

Comment: Newer `bash` allows you to write `(*posix*)` instead to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you very much I thought that was the case but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Why not just do `set -o posix` ? Is there any reason to do this `case` switch? Why do `set -o` and then check for `*posix*` ?

Comment: @user3625976  The question would be nicer if you would [link to the original script](https://github.com/carlobaldassi/gimp-lqr-plugin/blob/master/configure#L25). Looking at the script and the [commit](https://github.com/carlobaldassi/gimp-lqr-plugin/commit/93c022a426217e75da52ded7eb23f0e96296ed2e) it looks only like a cosmetics way carlobaldassi does case in bash, he does `case ... #(` and `;; #(`. I believe this is for editors to handle `)` braces right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anything that is after `#` in a line is considered as a comment. See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/case-esac-statement.htm) for the switch case syntax.